# Facebook Graph API - Unsupported GET request for accessing Facebook Ads Campaigns?

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

I'm running into an issue with an app I have in development. I have my Facebook app all setup, I'm able to grab a user's access_token via Firebase auth login, yet when I try to make some calls to the Facebook Graph API related to ad accounts/campaigns, etc., I'm getting an error:

`Unsupported get request. Object with ID '<ad-account-id>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api`

I'm using Angular and in my component, I've got an `ngOnInit()` function that is trying to execute the most basic version of grabbing the data:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log('auth', this.auth)
    let accessToken = '<access-token-i-dont-want-to-share>';
    let url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/<ad-account-id>/campaigns?access_token=${accessToken}`;

    let obs = this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      console.log('data', data);
    });
  }
```

I've added the appropriate permissions `ads_management`, `ads_read` on Facebook login, as well.

For my ad account ID, I pulled it straight from the Facebook Ads Power Editor so I know that's my correct ID.

I've also made my app Public with no country restrictions.

Can anyone else recommend to me something else I'm doing wrong? When I try to query the API for other things, it works no problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would suggest that you test the request in Graph API Explorer, to make sure it is not a problem with your code. If, with the same access token, you get the same error in there, then that most likely means that you are either missing a necessary permission, or do not have the rights to access this particular add account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ad-account-id>` should be in following format: `act_xxxxxxxxxx`
where `xxxxxxxx` is numeric account id